# Snap with NFS Shares

Tags: 18.04, software-center, snap, nfs, apparmor

Just switched to Ubuntu and am having issues accessing files stored on my NFS share when I use GIMP, VLC, and Audacity. All other software works great with my NFS shares. After spending a day researching this I finally stumbled upon the reason and it's that these were the apps I installed using the Ubuntu Software Center instead of via the command line and they use something called Snap.

I don't mount my entire home folder from the NFS, just a few directories inside of it like Documents, Videos, Pictures and some folders I created like eBooks, Work, etc.

Turning on the permission to "Read/write files on removable storage devices" doesn't fix it. Some people gave workaround to modify some apparmour config files, but that seemed like if you were mounting your entire home directory. I can't find a workaround for my specific use-case.

Should I just not be using Ubuntu Software Center since I use NFS for almost all of my files? Is there a better solution? I like browsing for software sometimes, and I feel like it's easier to trust something if it's in Ubuntu's software center than if I just willy-nilly add repositories and install stuff I see on the web.

Comment: Still a problem on 20.04

Comment: Still a problem on 22.04